# Появляется серая полоса

Tags: html, css

Есть `div` у него на фоне изображение,затем,чтобы затемнить картинку,накладываю на блок,другой блок со следующим классом

```
 .bg{ 
position: absolute;
z-index: 15;
width: 100%;

min-height:200px;
max-height:250px;
background: #000;
opacity: 0.5;
  }
```

Проблема в том,что стоит 100% ширина,но появляется серая полоска(кусок этого блока с классом `bg`)

Тут все видно https://jsfiddle.net/4aebh2bo/2/

Comment: Ой опечатка,спасибо.Я решил проблему,она в том ,нужно родителю задать `position:relative;`

Comment: да я только хотел это написать )

Comment: Либо вроде можно убрать `position: absolute;` в bg

Comment: @Batanichek,Спасибо!